# PHP class to add pages and fields in admin panel

Tags: options, api

I'm trying to build a little class to help build some simple input fields into a custom page in WordPress admin panel, here's what I've got:

```
<?php

class create_panel {

public $default_settings = Array('blog_banner_image' => 'main.jpg');

public function set_ref_name( $str ) {
    $this->ref_name = $str; 
}

public function set_sidebar_title( $str ) {
    $this->side_bar_title = $str;   
}

public function create_panel() {
    add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'admin_menu'));
    add_action('admin_head', array(&$this, 'admin_head'));
    if ( function_exists( 'register_sidebar' ) )
        register_sidebar( array( 'name' => 'Sidebar' ) );
    if ( ! is_array( get_option( $this->ref_name ) ) )
        add_option( $this->ref_name, $this->default_settings);
    $this->options = get_option( $this->ref_name );
}

public function admin_menu() {
    add_theme_page('Theme Control Panel', self::$this->side_bar_title, 'edit_themes', $array_name, array(&$this, 'optionsmenu'));
}

public function admin_head() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/code/' . $array_name . '.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
}

public function set_input_fields( $array ) {
    if( ! is_array( $array ) ) {
        Throw new Exception('set_input_field() perams must be an array.');  
    }else{
        foreach( $array as $input_arrays ) {
            if( count( $input_arrays ) != 3 ) {
                Throw new Exception('Perams must per input must total 3. input type, name and label');  
            }else{
                $type = $input_arrays[0];
                $name = $input_arrays[1];
                $label = $input_arrays[2];
                if( ! isset( $this->inputs->{$name} ) ) {
                    $this->inputs->{$name} = array( 'type' => $type, 'label' => $label );
                }else{
                    Throw new Exception('Cannot redeclair input perams.');  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public function optionsmenu() {
    if ( $_POST['ss_action'] == 'save' ) {
        if( isset( $this->inputs ) ) {
            foreach( $this->inputs as $name => $array ) {
                $this->options[(string)$name] = $_POST[$name];  
            }
            update_option( $this->ref_name, $this->options );
            echo '<div class="updated fade" id="message" style="background-color: rgb(255, 251, 204); width: 300px; margin-left: 20px"><p>Settings <strong>saved</strong>.</p></div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" class="themeform">
        <input type="hidden" id="ss_action" name="ss_action" value="save">
        <h2>Edit Static Text</h2>
        <?php
        if( isset( $this->inputs ) ) {
            foreach( $this->inputs as $name => $array ) {
                switch( $array['type'] ) {
                    case 'text' :
                        echo '<p><label style="display: inline-block; width: 150px; vertical-align: top;">' . $array['label'] . '</label><input type="text" name="' . (string)$name . '" id="" value="' . $this->options[(string)$name] . '" /><p>';
                    break;  
                }
            } 
        }
        ?>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="cp_save"/></p>
    </form>
<?php
    }
}

try{
    $cp = new create_panel();
    $cp->set_ref_name( 'styles' );
    $cp->set_sidebar_title( 'Edit Styles' );
    $cp->set_input_fields( array( array( 'text','telephone','Telephone:' ) ) );
}catch(Exception $err){
    die( $err->getMessage() );  
}
```

it seems to work but then when i reload the page the data has not saved.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) first. But maybe ["OptionTree"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/option-tree/screenshots/) will help you even more.

Comment: Option Tree is very cool. Haven't known about it. Thank you.

Comment: @Rilwis: You're welcome. Btw: Your meta box class is kool too.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial that may help you: [Incorporating the Settings API in WordPress Themes](http://bit.ly/hHjo6n). I don't use the Class method, but perhaps the tutorial may be helpful.